# How to Implement SSO in Openbravo

Tags: single-sign-on, cas, openbravo

In the openbravo wiki it is mentioned that SSO is one of the module of openbravo but found it to be an archive document. Is it still available in openbravo, if it is available how can I implement it? I tried implementing it using "http://www.wirabumisoftware.com/en/openbravo-developer-guide/openbravoerpdevtutorial/2-oberphowtoid/51-openbravoerpssohowto?start=3" this link, the problem is my openbravo is not redirecting to CAS server but my lam server is redirecting to CAS server and I'm able to login to the CAS server but again I need to login to openbravo application seperately.

Please help me fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below mentioned openbravo wiki for Authentication

http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/Authentication

Comment: Well thanks for the reply I'm now able to redirect to the CAS server and even able to login successfully but the session in getting expired Immediately and getting null pointer exception